# How can OTP (one time password) be protected against brute force attacks?

Tags: brute-force, owasp, one-time-password, one-time-pad

We have a feature in our application that ask for a six digit OTP before doing certain functions. It is sent via SMS and expiration is 5 mins. There has been an internal penetration test that exposed that this is vulnerable to brute-force attacks. What can we do programmatically to prevent this?

Comment: Shorten the time to like 30 secs, make the code longer 6 chars or so and use a strong algo to generate them. Implement code that locks users out after several failed attempts or at least add a captcha after some failed attempts.

Comment: its already 6 digits

Comment: i can think of 2 contending approaches: [1] let your OTP remain valid for entire (short) lifetime of txn like say ~ 10 minutes and build customer-level rate-limits in your OTP verification API (like max 5 verification attempts every 30 seconds) [2] invalidate OTP after ~ 10 failed verification attempts. i also like `@Nick M`'s idea of throwing a captcha after every 'n' failed verification attempts -> this would be incorporate the goodness of both the approaches told earlier

Comment: Irrespective of the approach taken above, for sensitive applications, make sure you consider safeguards against timing attack where attacker could send a barrage of concurrent requests to befool your counter / rate-limiting mechanisms. as they say [here](https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks) `"Note that although adding a delay could slow a single-threaded attack, it is less effective if the attacker sends multiple simultaneous authentication requests"`

Answer (score 0):

- Use a long text for OPT like 6-10 chars long. Which will provide a lot of combinations factorial(N). Which will be a very big number that no ordinary system can guess that OTP in 5 minutes.
- Use not only numbers but also characters which can make your OTP more strong.